# How to add numbers pagination to this blog page?

Tags: pagination, blog

I want to add number pagination to my blog page. I have tried to add pagination code but it does not appear.
here is the code and I want to add numbers pagination to it. it is blog page

```
<?php
               $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post'
                );
            
                $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
                while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $post_query->the_post();
                    ?>

         <div class="cbp-item">
            <div class="news_item shadow">
               <a class="image" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                  <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Latest News" class="img-responsive">
               </a>
               <div class="news_desc">
                  <h3 class="text-capitalize font-light darkcolor"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
                  <ul class="meta-tags top20 bottom20">
                     <li><a href="#."><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php echo get_the_date( 'M d' ); ?></a></li>
                     <li><a href="#."> <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php the_author_posts_link();?> </a></li>
                     <li><a href="#."><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <p class="bottom35"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="button btnprimary btn-gradient-hvr">Read more</a>
               </div> 
            </div> 
         </div> 

         <?php
            }
        }
        
           ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to get the paged query variable and pass it to your main query args:

```
//Protect against arbitrary paged values
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
    'paged' => $paged,
);
```

Then you have to add the following code at the place where you want the pagination to appear:

```
<?php
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
     
    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
        'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total'     => $post_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your reply. please, where could I put the first code in the blog?

Comment: Are you using a custom template for your blog? If yes then you can put it there. In general whenever you are making a WP_Query and you want to have pagination you are following the above process. Let me know if that worked :)

Comment: ```                                                                                                                                                                                         
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
    'paged' => $paged,
);                                                                                                                                                    ``` where should I put this code in the code I provided above? or in functions.php?